# Generators of $SL(n,F),GL(n,F),SO(n,R),O(n,R),U(n,C)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How can you describe Generators of $SL(n,F),GL(n,F),SO(n,R),O(n,R),U(n,C)$, where $F$ is a finite field, $R$ is real numbers and $C$ is complex numbers, $GL$ is a general linear group, $SL$ is a special linear group, $SO$ is a special ortogonal group, $O$ is an ortogonal group...

Comment: You can describe the generators by transvections, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group#Generators_and_relations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Over finite fields, the papers:

D. Taylor, Pairs of Generators for Matrix groups {I}, The Cayley Bulletin 3, (1987), 76-85

MR1823074  Howlett, R. B.; Rylands, L. J.; Taylor, D. E. Matrix generators for exceptional groups of Lie type. J. Symbolic Comput. 31 (2001), no. 4, 429–445.

MR1615330   Rylands, L. J.; Taylor, D. E. Matrix generators for the orthogonal groups. J. Symbolic Comput. 25 (1998), no. 3, 351–360.

describe generators. The systems GAP and Magma implement these.